# After i downloaded the new iOS 5 for my iPhone 4 safari isn't any different?

Tags: iphone, safari, ios

i downloaded the new iOS 5 for my iPhone 4 and safari is the same as it was and i was under the assumption that it would be somewhat different?

Answer (score 2):

There are some under-the-hood improvements to performance, and also some changes to the settings (such as a private browsing option), but there aren't any major changes to the Mobile Safari interface on the iPhone. The iPad version now has tabbed browsing instead of the window-switcher, but the iPhone is too small for such a thing to work.

The two features you may notice are Reading List and Reader. Reading List is essentially a  bookmarks folder that can sync with desktop Safari. You can add items to it from the Share item (centre button on the bottom toolbar). Reader will reformat some webpages (long articles) to make them more readable, removing ads and menus so that you've just got the text. You can access it from the grey Reader button in the address bar once the site loads (note that it's not available on all sites, just those that Safari can competently reformat).

Answer (score 1):

It includes the Reading List feature:

[image]

The Reader function to pull out articles from messy and convicted websites (like BBC or CNN):

[image]

And contains a slew of performance enhancements and changes under the hood. Other than that, it should look and behave quite the same as its predecessor. Apple [covers the new features](http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html#safari) if you'd like to read more about them.

Comment: I do have the "Reading List", but the "Reader" function doesn't seem to appear on my 3GS phone. Reader wont work there?

Comment: I've not heard Reader being specific to the later generation devices. It could be that you haven't gone to a website that features an article Reader can parse. Try here: http://www.anandtech.com/show/4902/intel-ssd-710-200gb-review If you still don't see te Reader button in the address bar, then it's likely the 3GS fails to support it.

Comment: I see! It does work, so apparently some websites will work and some others wont?

Comment: It's not site dependent more than code dependent. If Reader can parse an article, it'll show up. You'll find even some pages here on Stack Exchange can be viewed by Reader. It's all in how a page is coded.